# How to properly add a dependency to a module that's on the same level using Gradle in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, gradle, wildfly

I have a plain Java EE project that I am porting over to Gradle.
The structure I have created in Intellij Idea consists of these sub-projects:

```
\ee_forum_gradle (Uses ear plugin and deploys both the ejb and web project)
\ee_forum_gradle_ejb
\ee_forum_gradle_web (Uses war plugin and is dependent on the ejb project)
```

My problem is that the web project depends on the ejb project and I have to click *add dependency on module 'ee_forum_gradle_ejb_main'* in the web project every time I open it up in Intellij, because every time gradle is running the imports, this setting gets lost.

I tried to import the ejb project into the web project using gradle. 
So I added

```
includeFlat 'ee_forum_gradle_ejb'
```

to the settings.gradle of the web project and

```
compile project(':ee_forum_gradle_ejb')
```

to the build.gradle file of the web project. If I then try to run it on my Wildfly 10 server I get the following error:

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".deploymentCompleteService","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager","jboss.persistenceunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#forum-jpa\""],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".component.PostBean.START is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#forum-jpa\"]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldStartService is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#forum-jpa\"]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".beanmanager]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".component.UserBean.START is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#forum-jpa\"]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".component.ThreadBean.START is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#forum-jpa\"]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".deploymentCompleteService]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"ee_forum_gradle_ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".component.BoardBean.START is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"ee_forum_gradle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear/ee_forum_gradle_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war#forum-jpa\"]"]}
```

Any ideas on how to get this Gradle project running are much appreciated. Like I wrote, if I click on *add dependency on module..* the project is running successfully but I have to repeat this step every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution is to use

```
include('ee_forum_gradle_ejb')
```

in the settings.gradle file of the web project and then

```
providedCompile project(':ee_forum_gradle_ejb')
```

in the build.gradle file of the web project.

I think the problem with just using compile, instead of providedCompile, is that the ejb project is included twice and that's confusing the server somehow.